# How to insert a blob using Zend

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, blob

How can i insert a blob into a blob column  in an oracle database using zend db, i tried looking in Zend documentation but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this,

```
  $blobimage = file_get_contents("path/to/some/image");
  $data = array('blobcolumn' => $blobimage);
  $this->insert(bin2hex($data));
```

`$this` points to `Zend_Db_Table`

Comment: thanks , i tried but im getting ORA-01465: invalid hex number , why  is that ?

Comment: just used bin2hex to convert my binary file to an hex number :  $this->insert(bin2hex($data)); and it worked